# Do functions of the `fmt` package support formatters for arrays?

Tags: serialization, go

I am trying to submit an email with multiple paramaters and I have emails in a separate file with some printing verbs, but since there are so many verbs I end up with a line like this:

```
message := fmt.Sprintf(util.CONTACT_EMAIL, form.Name, form.Email, form.Email,     form.Phone, form.Phone, form.Message, ...)
```

and it just goes on and on which looks bad. And the reason I repeat some verbs is to get the href's, for example `<a href"mailto:%s">%s</a>`, and so forth. If anyone has a better approach to that I'd really like to know.

But on to my question.. Does Go have a formatter that works similar to 
[vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) in PHP? It basically takes an array as the arguments so it would be like:

```
string vsprintf(string $format , array $args)
```

..instead of the mess I have above, which allows it to be a bit more readable.

I looked on the docs but don't seem to see anything..but a lot of what Go does is still foreign to me so maybe I overlooked it.

Comment: Does `%v`, with either of the `#` or `+` flags not work for you?

Comment: Depending on your usage, I would recommend looking at templating. See: [`text/template`](https://godoc.org/text/template) and [`html/template`](https://godoc.org/html/template).

Comment: Not to mention "encoding/json", or external packages like https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew

Comment: Hmm thank you both for the links. I was actually already using html/template for my views but I could probably also use them for emails.. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pass a slice of arguments to `fmt.Sprintf` (or any other function that takes a variadic number of arguments) you can do that like this:

```
func main() {
    s := []interface{}{1,2,5}
    z := fmt.Sprintf("%d, %d, %d", s...)
    print(z)
}
```

or if you have a slice of anything that isn't the empty interface, we have to copy it into a slice of the empty interface:

```
func main() {
    s := []int{1,2,5}

    // we need to copy each element one-by-one into a []interface{} 
    // because they are laid out differently in memory in go.
    var x []interface{}
    for _, i := range s {
        x = append(x, i)
    }

    // pass the contents of the new slice into sprintf
    z := fmt.Sprintf("%d, %d, %d", x...)
    print(z)
}
```

Comment: That works.. How would this work in congruence with my Form struct? I see some docs on how I could use an interface in my struct by naming a field and making its type the interface.. would that Form struct then have access to the interface inside of it? (I basically just want to do that for separations of concerns.. my Form struct is my "model" so I don't want to create the interface inside the controller, which is what your example would be doing for me).